# Visual Studio Class Icon Changes When Inheriting from WebClient

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Once I change the class to inherit from WebClient, the file icon changes to the icon seen at the bottom of the screenshot. What does that icon reflect?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what happens when you inherit (directly or indirectly) from `System.ComponentModel.Component`. Sure enough, `WebClient` inherits from `Component`.

Try that: create a new file with a class, and then make the class inherit from `Component`. The icon will change at once.

So the icon designates a *component*, which often happen to have designers associated with them, but it's mostly some UI fanciness.